# Write data from SQLite Table to CSV file (flask)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, csv, flask

Bit of a beginner here, so excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to add a feature that allows users to download their user-specific transactional data as a CSV file. The data is stored in a sqlite table titled 'acctransactions'

This is what I've currently got:

```
@app.route("/trans_csv")
@login_required
def trans_csv():
    si = io.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    rows = db.execute("SELECT (id, acc_transaction, deposit, withdrawl, cash)  FROM acctransactions WHERE id = :user_id VALUES(:id, :acc_transaction, :deposit, :withdrawl, :cash)", id=session["user_id"],  deposit=deposit, withdrawl=withdrawl, cash=cash["cash"])

    cw.writerows(rows)

    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=accounttransactions.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

The error I get in response to the code currently is: "NameError: name 'withdrawl' is not defined"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Why would it have a problem with withdrawl but not with deposit?

Comment: the error is justified and descriptive

Comment: Do you in fact have a variable named `withdrawl` in scope there?

Comment: I've added further lines to it, which explicitly define each variable as it goes through. First time it was withdrawl, then cash, now it has a problem with user_id.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the list of columns in the SELECT list.  That syntax is valid for many other SQL clauses, but not the SELECT statement.

Comment: Really you need to be more specific.  You should be getting a specific line for which the error occurs, and it is critical for you in fixing the problem and others who you ask to help.  Please edit the question with more specific details about the error.  Also, sometimes the end-goal is useful to share, but it seems that the errors are for the SQL statement.  That comes before the export to CSV and as far as this question goes, it is a completely separate issue from exporting to CSV.  You need to successfully debug and understand the SQL before getting help with the CSV export portion.

Comment: The VALUES clause is not valid after the WHERE clause.  What is your intention with the VALUES clause?  Usually one selects values with a few key columns.  There should be no need to specify (or re-specify) other values.  Not only does that really not make sense to do that, it is likely for there to be conflicts between values in the database and values being passed to the query.  Was your intention to first do an update, then query afterwards?

Comment: I'm not intending for it to update or really query anything; it does both in other sections. All I want it to do is take the data, specific to the user and place it within the CSV. Do you have any recommendations on how to solve the SQL statement issue?